# How to pass same prop twice to vue component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

It is possible to do this with vue:

```js
const someComputedClass = 'otherClass'
<Foo class="someClass" :class="someComputedClass" />
```

You can pass class and :class and it will merge both. I am aware that the class attribute has some kind of special handling here. However, I would like to have this behavior for a prop of my own component as well.

```js
const someComputedProp = 'otherValue'
<Foo prpp="someValue" :prop="someComputedProp " />
```

Is there a way to achieve this (maybe with custom merge strategies) or is this completely impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge strategies are used to control [merging of overlapping options](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Custom-Option-Merge-Strategies) from the Options API & mixins when the component is created.

Special handling of `style` and `class` props is a runtime thing and it works only because Vue devs decided it is a useful thing to do and implemented it that way.

What you want is not possible unless Vue devs decides to implement it... which I doubt - because implementing it for `class` and `style` is straightforward as the "output" is well defined by HTML standard. Implement the same thing for any `prop` is much more difficult because you don't know the data type of the prop in advance (as opposed to `class` and `style`) - i.e. how would merging work if the data type of the prop is `Number` or `String` ?

**TL:DR**

It is not possible. Move on...

Comment: Your link links to custom merge which is exactly what I need. That actually makes it possible, doesn't it?

Comment: Well, not really. As I said - merge strategies are used **before the component is created** to merge different "options" objects (from component definition and from mixins). What you want has nothing to do with component creation...